# For the Avalon 741, would a suitable PSU be the Leadex II 1200W?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-setup, psu, avalon

It is remarkably difficult to get the suggested EVGA SuperNOVA 1300 W PSU to the UK. I am wondering if this PSU would be likely a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, given that you need 96A and the power supply supplies 99A. It's not a lot of headroom, though. (In contrast, the EVGA power supply has 108A.)